# png resolution is wrong when opening file from the UV/Image Editor

Tags: texturing, image, uv-image-editor

I was sent an png for a texture by a friend.
The image is 192 x 24 pixels
[image: Image from Friend]
it's properties are correct in windows explorer when I view the downloaded file, but as soon as I open it in blender...it's y pixels are halved so it's very much blender. but I don't know why.

If I use the blender Image Editor and Alt+S to save the image again, the original is converted to 192 x 12 (Which is half the y)

[image: Distorted Aspect Ratio]

Answer (score 2):

You need to Uncheck the Fields checkbox

[image]
[image]

Comment: Care to add some more information to your answer? :)

Comment: The ***Field*** box should only be enabled if you are dealing with interlaced images. Interlaced images store the information for the odd and even lines of a single frame separately. Those lines have to be recombined to form a full frame, like [this image](http://t3rfde.com/wp-content/uploads/2014/01/HDTV-Interlaced.jpg). In general is a technology used in video to achieve smoother motion at the expense of spatial resolution. . read: https://www.animemusicvideos.org/guides/avtech/video2.htm